# How to remove keys of type `never`?

Tags: typescript

I've created this utility type called `Override` which I find quite handy, but one thing that's been bothering me is that it's not very convenient to completely *remove* properties.

In the example below, I want `Bar` to retain `a` from `Foo`, override `b` to be a `string` instead of a `number`, and remove `c`. However, `c` sticks around, it's just typed as `never`. How can I remove all the nevers intead?

```
type Override<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & B

type Foo = {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: boolean
}

type Bar = Override<Foo, {
    b: string
    c: never
}>

function f(bar: Bar) {
   console.log(bar.c)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhAToglgEwgHgIIBooBCAfFALywC2KwO+A1hCAPYBmhJAZIQFDeiRQAYkyZkoAb25RpUAIYAuKAGdgqAHYBzKTIBGitQFcKOpNukBjRTpEAbCLLXcAvr37QCsxGPhJUGTMJM+JIyUHrKqiiaZlCWUGoQCIjORLwsBmrmwChMalAsABQ6nooeiACUEmbmuUpMdgB0NkwaRZ4N5uXO3EA)

Comment: @smac89 I'm not choosing `c: boolean`. I want to **remove** `c`. The property should not exist on `Bar` at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than `& B`, you can intersect with a mapping of a new object type with the never values removed.

```
type Override<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & {
    [K in keyof B as B[K] extends never ? never : K]: B[K]
}
```

This can be extended to remove any sort of value you want.

```
type Override<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & {
    [K in keyof B as B[K] extends never | void ? never : K]: B[K]
}
```

Comment: I think `void` might be a little funky actually. Looks like it wants to remove explicitly `undefined` properties as well, which isn't what I wanted. That's OK tho, I can live with just removing the nevers. Will accept this answer when it lets me in 3 min, thank you :D

Comment: Just discovered this is doing something weird with generics: https://go.mpen.ca/9hfzc It's removing properties of type `T`. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

found a related issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199

```
type Override<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & B

type Foo = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
}

type FilteredKeys<T> = {
  // this does not work
  // [K in keyof T]: K

  // this do
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : K
}[keyof T]

type RemoveNever<T> = {
  [K in FilteredKeys<T>]: T[K]
}

type Bar = RemoveNever<
  Override<
    Foo,
    {
      b: string
      c: never
      d: number
    }
  >
>

function f(bar: Bar) {
  console.log(bar.a)
  console.log(bar.b)
  console.log(bar.c)
  console.log(bar.d)
}
```

BTW, we thinks these two forms are same, but tsc does not

- `[K in keyof T]: K`
- `[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : K`